# How do I add check box in Form to show payment date?

Tags: excel, forms, checkbox

This is what I have in my Payment Form. I use a Combobox to pull the user info into the payments Form. The trouble I am having is it keeps showing TRUE in the Paid column. In another column to the right of Paid it shows 30 days out when next payment is due.

**I've tried this code but it puts it in all the cells in the column**

````
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Range("I:I").Value = Date
    Else: Range("I:I").Value = ""
End If

End Sub```



'Dim xRg As Range
'Updated by Extendoffice 2018/1/30
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Customer").Range("A2:F8")
    ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 2, False)
    TextBox2.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 3, False)
    TextBox3.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 4, False)
    TextBox4.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 5, False)
    TextBox5.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 6, False)
End Sub
Private Sub cbCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cbAdd_Click()

'dimmin Var
    Dim Data As Worksheet

'Setting Var
    Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payments")
    NextRow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 1) = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 2) = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 3) = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 4) = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 5) = Me.TextBox4.Value
    Data.Cells(NextRow, 7) = Me.CheckBox1.Value
    
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = ""
    
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = “TextBox” Or TypeName(ctl) = “ComboBox” Then
ctl.Value = “”
End If
Next ctl
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

User forms aren't designed or intended to control worksheet contents. Look upon your workbook like an airport with the passenger halls in the center and walkways leading to satellites with departure gates. One such satellite is is your payments form, another is your worksheet. To move data from one to the other you need to go through the hub. The hub in this picture is a standard code module, and it needs to be given control of your project. Use the code below as a frame. Paste it to a standard code module.

```
Sub MakePayment()

    Dim FrmPayment      As New PaymentForm
    Dim xRg             As Range
    
    With FrmPayment
        Set xRg = Worksheets("Customer").Range("A2:F8")
        .ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
        .Show
        
        If Val(.Tag) = 1 Then
            ' write to the sheet
        End If
    End With
    
    Unload FrmPayment
    Set FrmPayment = Nothing
End Sub
```

The scheme is simple. There is a user form named `PaymentForm` (better than "UserForm1"). When the above sub is run a new instance of that form is created, the combo box is loaded and control handed to the form (`.Show`). When the form is closed code execution resumes at that point, data will be removed from the form and written to the worksheet. Then the form is unloaded.

To let this work you mustn't unload the form in the form's code module. Instead use `Me.Hide` I suggest to use the Form's `Tag` property to send a signal back to the calling procedure. If it's 1 the data should be processed, otherwise nothing is to be done. Set the Tag value in the CommandOK procedure. If the user cancelled the property will be empty and `Val(.Tag)` will return 0.

Note that the `Initialize` event procedure runs when the form's instance is created, meaning at `Dim FrmPayment As New PaymentForm`. Your procedure tries to access the remote satellite (the worksheet) directly. Not good. Better to load the Cbx just before showing the form (but long after initialization) as I have done in my above code. At that point you have access to all controls of the form and you can also endow the "PAID" textbox with a value of your choice.

`Me.Hide` (in the form's module) hides the form and hands control back to the calling procedure. At that point all form controls and their values are accessible through the object `FrmPayment` and so is the worksheet. You can transfer data from one satellite to the other - at the hub.

I didn't test the above code but it's simple and I expect it to have no errors. However, before you try it in your project make sure to disable the event procedures in your code that would interfere in the system, such as the `Initialize` event.